# Using a USB camera deletes /dev/video0

Tags: camera

## Problem

When I use the USB camera attached to my freshly booted Raspberry Pi 3, I'm able to capture a single image/video. But when I attempt to do this again, the camera (`/dev/video0`) seems to have disappeared completely... Rebooting allows to camera to be used again, but only for a single iteration.

## Additional info

- When I run `fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner test.jpg` to capture an image I get:

  `--- Opening /dev/video0...
  Trying source module v4l2...
  /dev/video0 opened.
  No input was specified, using the first.
  --- Capturing frame...
  Captured frame in 0.00 seconds.
  --- Processing captured image...
  Disabling banner.
  Writing JPEG image to 'test.jpg'.`

  However, if I run the exact same command again I get:

  `--- Opening /dev/video0...
  Trying source module v4l2...
  Error opening device: /dev/video0
  open: Device or resource busy
  Trying source module v4l1...
  Error opening device: /dev/video0
  open: No such file or directory
  Unable to find a source module that can read /dev/video0.`

  And running it a third time gives:

  `--- Opening /dev/video0...
  stat: No such file or directory`
- Also, running `ls /dev/video*` yields:

  `ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory`
- A similar effect is also observed using different methods for capturing the camera feed, e.g. using [motion](https://motion-project.github.io).

## Question

So why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked to append the following in the `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_mask=0x3
```

and then `reboot`

Found the answer on the [raspberry forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=197089)